Drawing convex hull that joins centroids of four nearest clusters with highest values
I have point layer in which I have calculated the DBSCAN clusters.
The field that stores the clusters is called 'class' and the values range from 1 to 9, plus NULL values.
As you can see in the screenshot, I use the following expression to draw the centroids corresponding to the grouping of the clusters plus the nearest NULL value points for each cluster:
centroid(
        collect($geometry,
        group_by:=if (
           class is NULL, 
           overlay_nearest (@layer, class, filter:=class is not NULL)[0],
           class
        )
        )
    )


In addition for each cluster I calculate the number of points it includes with the following function:
count($id, group_by:=if (
           class is NULL, 
           overlay_nearest (@layer, class, filter:=class is not NULL)[0],
           class
        ))


I would like to use these two expressions (or other alternative expression, but maintaining this analysis) to build a single expression for Geometry Generator that draws the Convex_hull that joins the centroids of the 4 nearest clusters with highest values. I add a simulation of the ones I am trying to get:

Unfinished solution proposed by Tom Brennan:
Next I add the proposed solution that the user Tom Brennan has worked on. I have tried this solution and confirm that it partially solves the objective. The parts it solves are:

Get the conditional for 'class' field
Get the centroid for that 'class' field
Get the count for 'class' field

The missing parts are:

To get the centroids relating to the top 4 counts
Draw the convex hull of those centroids

I hope an expert user can take over this approach or to post an alternative approach to my question:
with_variable(
    'new_class',
    if (class is NULL,
        overlay_nearest(@layer, class, filter:=class is not NULL)[0],
        class),
    with_variable(
        'parent_id', @new_class,
        with_variable(
            'id_array',
            aggregate(@layer,
                aggregate:='array_agg',
                    expression:=to_string(@id),
                    filter:=eval(if (class is NULL,overlay_nearest(
                    @layer,
                    class,
                    filter:=class is not NULL)[0],class))=@parent_id),
                    array(@new_class,
                        array_length(@id_array),
                        centroid(collect_geometries(array_foreach(
                            @id_array,
                            geometry(get_feature_by_id(@layer,@element)))))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )


Why is the light blue 10 in the bottom right not included (vs the yellow 8 in the top left)?

You are right. Sorry, my mistake in drawing the convex hull by hand. In fact, it would be formed by the centroids with value 56 (green color), 10 (fuchsia color), 10 (light blue color) and 24 (green color).

I have updated the question with the correct image

I'm assuming there's a reason that you can't classify the NULL points to their nearest cluster before doing the convex hull?

Yes, I could classify the NULL points with the value of the nearest cluster, before drawing the convex hull, but as I am working on an on-the-fly project, my idea is to save this step by using the conditional instruction  if (class is NULL, overlay_nearest (@layer, class, filter:=class is not NULL)[0]
If it is possible, I would like to keep this idea

Interesting question. I suspect it is possible, but the expression is likely to be complex. You need to do multiple iterations through the points - to get the conditional class, to get the centroid for that class, to get the count for that class, to get the centroids relating to the top 4 counts (this may be the hardest part) and finally the convex hull of those centroids. I can get the first 3 bits, but that's still a way from a complete expression.

I'm away for a few days - this is what I have so far: with_variable('new_class',  if(class is NULL, overlay_nearest (@layer, class, filter:=class is not NULL)[0],class), with_variable('parent_id',@new_class, with_variable('id_array',  aggregate(@layer,      aggregate:='array_agg',      expression:=to_string(@id),      filter:=eval(if(class is NULL, overlay_nearest (@layer, class, filter:=class is not NULL)[0],class))=@parent_id),  array(@new_class,array_length(@id_array),centroid(collect_geometries(array_foreach(@id_array,geometry(get_feature_by_id(@layer,@element))))))) ))

For each point, this gives an array of the (new) class, count, and centroid. I haven't worked out where to go from here, or if this is actually the right path!

I think it is a good approach to use array. I take this idea and, for my part, I will continue to work, to see if I find a solution. Thank you very much Tom!

Tom, I check your proposal and seems to partially solve the objective, although it still is unfinished to create the convex hull.
With your permission, I add your expression code to the question to give more information to others expert users about this approach, and to see if this code can help to find the final solution

After the steps above, the next thing I want to do is to filter/sort one array based on another array of the same length. QGIS expressions have fairly basic array functions, and I can't see how to implement either of the more complex array functions using them.

Thank you very much for all your help and effort in finding a solution. Hopefully you will find the solution based on the idea of filtering/sorting an array based on another array.
For my part I keep the question open as I wourld like to use it in my research.
I encourage other expert users to take this question as a challenge to help you in your idea or to provide new approaches.
